# Mysql Sum over partition by

Tags: mysql, partition

Hi I am doing MySQL and using  'Sum over (partition by )'

I want to see the values are adding up by following lines like below

[image]

but my result is like just

[image]

I'm using the following query:

```
select dea.location, sum(cast(vac.new_vaccinations as signed)) over (partition by dea.location order by dea.location)
From pr.CovidDeaths_csv dea
join pr.CovidVaccinations_csv vac
    on dea.location = vac.location
    and dea.date = vac.date
    where dea.continent is not null
    order by 2;
```

Does anyone know about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [frame specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) for window functions in MySQL. It allows you to apply a cumulative sum instead of a static sum:

```
select dea.location, 
       sum(cast(vac.new_vaccinations as signed)) 
           over(partition by dea.location 
                order by dea.location     ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
From pr.CovidDeaths_csv dea
join pr.CovidVaccinations_csv vac
    on dea.location = vac.location
    and dea.date = vac.date
    where dea.continent is not null
    order by 2;
```

As you've not shared your data from all your tables, I cannot replicate your case, but you can see an analogous pattern on sample data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6nVvpdfoMVSxrv3xR3GQm/1).